# Disable editing in Ag grid on cell value change event

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

In my angular project, I'm using Ag-grid `cellValueChange` event, so whenever any cell value changes, the corresponding row gets into edit mode, I have applied some CSS to that row just to make sure editing is active on the current row.
But now I want other grid rows should become non-editable so that the user cannot edit 2 rows at the same time.
I have used `gridOptions.suppressClickEdit = true` on event call, but it makes all grid rows as non-editable which I don't want, I want to keep current row away from getting non-editable.

Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you considered using this gridOption  stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus=true; to make sure when you click on other rows, editing stops.

Comment: @PratikBhat I guess you misunderstood my question. I want the entire grid to be non-editable except the row where **cellValueChange** event is called

Comment: technically a user cannot edit more than one row a a time, unless it is being updated from somewhere else. Also when you say no editable, are you referring to just removing the custom CSS? you will have to post more code so its fully understood what you are trying to achieve